# Create a video from a series of images using commandline

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, photo, exiftool

I have a few thousand images, each are jpg, and the filename is unix timestamp in milliseconds, which means each file name has gaps to the next filename, but all are sequential.

Does anyone know how to merge this into a video with a certain duration and/or frame rate? I was looking into FFMPEG, and ExifTool, but I don't think those do sequential merges that have gaps in the filename

I have tried the following threads:

- [ffmpeg from pngs... Error with subset of PNGS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48995558/ffmpeg-from-pngs-error-with-subset-of-pngs)
- [Using ffmpeg with not consecutive numbered files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806493/using-ffmpeg-with-not-consecutive-numbered-files)
- [ffmpeg img to video = Could find no file with path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47389201/ffmpeg-img-to-video-could-find-no-file-with-path)

I am using Windows so `-pattern_type glob` in `ffmpeg` is not an option.

Comment: Exiftool only deals with metadata and cannot be used to make a video.

Comment: See new duplicate link.